# What stops HtmlUnit from loading PSN store page?

Tags: javascript, java, web-scraping, kotlin, htmlunit

I'm trying to load Playstation Store page with HtmlUnit, but looks like everything that it loads is blank page with "Loading..." text (and a bit of javascript).
I used following configuration to make HtmlUnit work, but hopelessly (its kotlin):

```
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun homePage() {
    val webClient = WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER).apply {
        ajaxController = NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()
        options.isUseInsecureSSL = true
        options.isThrowExceptionOnScriptError = false
        options.isJavaScriptEnabled = true
        options.isCssEnabled = true
        options.isRedirectEnabled = true
        options.isThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode = false
        options.isUseInsecureSSL = true
        options.isDownloadImages = true
        cookieManager.isCookiesEnabled = true
        waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000)
        waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000)
    }

    val page = webClient.getPage<HtmlPage>("https://store.playstation.com/")
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    assertFalse(page.asXml().contains("Loading"))
}
```

I don't see any specific errors during loading the page:

```
мая 09, 2017 4:08:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript isExecutionNeeded
WARNING: Script is not JavaScript (type: application/json, language: ). Skipping execution.
мая 09, 2017 4:08:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://sonynetworkentertainment.112.2o7.net/b/ss/snestorewebloadglobal/1/chidv1/s75296982536092?AQB=1&ndh=1&t=9%2F5%2F2017%2016%3A8%3A22%202%20-180&ts=1494335302&vid=c61f4752-adfd-84d1-728c-187350f9aa37&pageName=web%3Aloading_start&v1=D%3DpageName&g=https%3A%2F%2Fstore.playstation.com%2F&r=&v2=xx-xx&ch=web%3Aloading_start&c68=D%3Dg&c72=web&v72=web&cc=USD&ce=UTF-8&server=web&events=event1&AQE=1
мая 09, 2017 4:08:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://store.playstation.com/kamaji/api/chihiro/00_09_000/geo
```

The question is: what stops HtmlUnit from loading the page? I tried to figure it myself, but the only idea I came is that it could be some kind of defense against headless browsers or very heavy JS that HtmlUnit doesn't support. But for example

> https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com

can be opened without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an SPA - [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Generally, SPAs have only basic markup, a container and the whole UI is rendered dynamically with frameworks like [React](https://reactjs.org/) or [Angular](https://angular.io/).

After stripping scripts and styles from the https://store.playstation.com what is left is:

```
<div id="waitAppLoading">
  <div class="waitHorizon">
    <div class="centerBox">
      <div class="logoCtnr"></div>
      <div class="textBox"><div class="spinCtnr"></div><div id="appLoadingMsg"></div></div>
      <div class="startupErr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="appRoot" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="lockdownScreen"></div>
<div id="global-wait">
  <div class="waitHorizon">
    <div class="waitContainer">
      <div class="sq1"></div>
      <div class="sq2"></div>
      <div class="sq3"></div>
      <div class="sq4"></div>
      <div class="sq5"></div>
      <div class="sq6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="global-ps-loader">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="notifierCtnr" class="mainCol"><div id="notifier-box"></div></div>
<div id="storeNotAvail"></div>
<div class="dimToolEl dimToolElProdTitle"></div>
<div class="dimToolEl dimToolElProdSubTitle"></div>
<div id="transact-iframe-container">
  <iframe id="transact-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

As you see, there is no content here, only wireframe for the app. The web client does not fully simulates browser, and does not execute that scripts. That's why you see an empty page.

Comment: Thank you, I know that it is SPA. But HtmlUnit can handle JS requests and it actually works on some SPAs. Looks like I've used waiting for JS execution in wrong way

Answer (score 0):

At least this java code works here. I got the language selection dialog like in real FF.
I'm using the latest HtmlUnit code. This is in general a good idea.

```
    String url = "https://store.playstation.com/";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52)) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000 * 10);

        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println(page.asText());
        System.out.println("----------------");

        HtmlElement btn = page.querySelector(".btn");
        System.out.println(btn.asXml());
        System.out.println("----------------");
    }
```

And please remove the calls

```
    waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000)
    waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000)
```

from your setup code. These methods are NOT setting any options; they are doing the wait at execution time.

Comment: Oh! So those methods should be called instead Thread.sleep(). Then, may be it will help to get over "Loading" screen. Will try that, thanks